# i cant call the sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote this function

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.MEDIAVTRINEW
    (@CODIGO VARCHAR(25), 
     @YEAR VARCHAR(4),    
     @TRI INT)
RETURNS TABLE   
    RETURN  (SELECT ROUND(ISNULL(SUM(D2.D2_QUANT) / 3, 0), 2) AS MEDIA
    FROM SD2010 D2  
    WHERE D2.D_E_L_E_T_ = ''        
      AND D2.D2_TES IN ('502', '506', '505')
      AND D2.D2_COD = @CODIGO  
      AND ((@TRI = 1 
            AND D2.D2_EMISSAO >= CONCAT(@YEAR, '01', '01')
            AND D2.D2_EMISSAO <= CONCAT(@YEAR, '03', '31')
           )
           OR
           (@TRI = 2 
            AND D2.D2_EMISSAO >= CONCAT(@YEAR, '04', '01')
            AND D2.D2_EMISSAO <= CONCAT(@YEAR, '06', '31')
           )
           OR
           (@TRI = 3 
            AND D2.D2_EMISSAO >= CONCAT(@YEAR, '07', '01')
            AND D2.D2_EMISSAO <= CONCAT(@YEAR, '09', '31')
           )
           OR
           (@TRI = 4 
            AND D2.D2_EMISSAO >= CONCAT(@YEAR, '10', '01')
            AND D2.D2_EMISSAO <= CONCAT(@YEAR, '12', '31')
           )
          )
     )
GO
```

and tried to call the function below but it didn't appear in the dropdown, and I get this error:

> Could not find colunm dbo or the use defined function or agreggate, or the name is ambiguous

when I tried to use this function:

```
SELECT dbo.MEDIAVTRINEW('001004', '20171201', 4)
```

PS: I executed the function alone throwing the parameters and it worked.

Comment: are you using ms sql server?

Comment: Since the function is returning a table, you should call it in the `FROM` clause.  `SELECT * FROM dbo.MEDIAVTRINEW('001004','20171201',4)`

Comment: There's neither a 31st of June (06) nor a 31st of September (09) - you should fix those errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `FROM` clause to call table valued function. Your syntax works for a scalar function

```
Select * from dbo.MEDIAVTRINEW('001004','20171201',4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Being a **Table-Valued Function**, I suspect you need either a **CROSS APPLY** or **OUTER APPLY**

**Example**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply dbo.MEDIAVTRINEW('001004','20171201',4) B
```

Use **OUTER APPLY** to see nulls

Replace the parameters with your field values